# PostSharp OnMethodBoundaryAspect with Abstract Methods

Tags: methods, abstract, postsharp

I'm new to PostSharp and investigating it's use for our project. I'm trying to apply OnMethodBoundaryAspect on an abstract method and getting the following error: http://screencast.com/t/1LyzIz2M

Able to execute the aspect just fine with regular and virtual methods, am I missing anything or is it not possible w/ abstract members?

Here's my simple aspect:

```
[Serializable]
public sealed class TraceAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    protected string _strMethodName;
    protected static readonly Stopwatch _sw = new Stopwatch();

    public TraceAttribute(string pMethodName)
    {
        _strMethodName = pMethodName;
    }

    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        _sw.Start();
        string strMsg = string.Format(">> Entering {0}.{1}", args.Method.DeclaringType.Name, args.Method);
        Debug.Print(strMsg);
    }

    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        _sw.Stop();
        string strMsg = string.Format("<< Leaving {0}.{1} - EXECTIME: {2} ms", args.Method.DeclaringType.Name,
                                      args.Method, _sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Debug.Print(strMsg);

        _sw.Reset();
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Postsharp - Adding OnMethodBoundaryAspect to abstract Method - Aspect Not Firing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433934/postsharp-adding-onmethodboundaryaspect-to-abstract-method-aspect-not-firing)